# Calculate in two variable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculator

I am new developer. I want calculate between two variables "packageprice" and "eventprice". How to addition in this two variable and result show in

```
<div id="result">
```

like: packageprice + eventprice = result

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#asdasd option', function(){  
    jQuery('#ssss').val(jQuery(this).val());            
    var packageprice = jQuery("#rrrr").text(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
}); 

jQuery(document).on('click', '#event  option', function(){  
    jQuery('#ssss').val(jQuery(this).val()); 
    var eventprice = jQuery("#eventprice").text(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: 1, please show your html structure too.  2, when do you want to do the calculation - on click of each button or when you click a different button to the bindings shown above? 3.  what's ssss and rrrr?  4 unless the id is a price, and the option has an id, then this code won't work.  Please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question

Comment: You can't use `click` on `<option>`. Events on `<option>` are not supported cross browser

Comment: Provide sample html for a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

First of all declaring your variables inside a block would mean that the value is preserved in that variable only till the block ends. After that the variable is destroyed. So take both your variables out the blocks and declare them above the first block.

```
var packageprice;
var eventprice;
```

And to display "packageprice + eventprice = result" you'll have to do something like this on whichever event you want this code to run:

```
$('#result').html(packageprice + '+' + eventprice + '=' (parseInt(packageprice)+parseInt(eventprice)));
```